# Error installing Active Directory Certificate Services

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, ad-certificate-services, windows-server-core

I'm trying to install Active Directory Certificate Services on a Windows Server 2016 Standard Core VM where I logged in with the Administrator account.

I ran the following Powershell cmdlet:

```
ps> Add-WindowsFeature Adcs-Cert-Authority -IncludeManagementTools
ps> Install-AdcsCertificateAuthority -CAType EnterpriseRootCA
```

The first cmdlet succeeded, but then the second command fails with the following error message:

```
> Active Directory Certificate Services setup failed with the following
> error:  A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of
> values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed ADDS role (in the same server or another)? There are a few requirements that you need to meet in order to install and configure ADCS in a environment. Also you need an account that is member of both, Enterprise Admins group and Domain Admins group. Please be sure to [check this MS docs reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/install-the-certification-authority) to confirm you have the requirements for this.

In case everything from the above is correct (since you say the first cmdlet succeeded) check the the second cmdlet syntax since it seems to be wrong (at least what you posted), it's `Install-AdcsCertificationAuthority` as you can [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adcsdeployment/install-adcscertificationauthority?view=win10-ps)